# Create Best Query For Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Hey i am trying to create some queries which should work like "where ..... 
and .... and" in sql. 
i have tried boolQuery for that purpose eg;

```
boolQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldCity, 
city), 0), Occur.FILTER)); 
boolQueryBuilder.add(new BooleanClause(new WildcardQuery(new Term(fieldText, 
str)), Occur.SHOULD)); 
boolQueryBuilder.add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldText, strTemp), fuzzy), 
Occur.SHOULD); 
boolQueryBuilder.add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldText, mergedKeyword), 
fuzzy), Occur.SHOULD);
```

These are one of  my query generator builders element. But problem is its 
not working like "AND" operation "FILTER" or "MUST" return all values with 
given field when "SHOULD" queries  not match with any result.

I want to have speed return so i want to have less result for each search. 
Can someone give me advices about my problem.

Have nice work.

Comment: Your English is very hard to understand. It's not clear why Occur.MUST doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry. i know that i am not good at english. Just i have reseached this topic but didnt achive this problem so wanted to ask here. Occur.MUST is working but problem  for my case is when Occur.SHOULD  wont return any result then  total result will be  Occur.MUST  all result which is a huge result for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you are getting back all of the results with matches on fieldCity, whether you have a match on fieldText or not, and you want all results to have at least one match on fieldText.

What you have now is basically: `+city text1 text2 text3`. The only term required to match is the city. The rest of the term will impact the score, but won't restrict the result set. If you want to make sure you get at least one fieldText match, you could change the query to look more like this: `+city +(text1 text2 text3)`:

```
BooleanQuery fieldTextSubQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .add(new WildcardQuery(new Term(fieldText, str), Occur.SHOULD)
    .add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldText, strTemp), fuzzy), Occur.SHOULD)
    .add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldText, mergedKeyword), fuzzy), Occur.SHOULD)
    .build();

BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term(fieldCity, city), 0), Occur.FILTER)
    .add(textSubQuery, Occur.MUST)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked . i wanted +city +(text1 text2 text3) as you told . and  now i can get correct  results in topResult